# Is it possible to autocomplete fields in Sharepoint with user info?

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory, autocomplete

I'm in charge of a Sharepoint collection, and a user asks this. Is it possible that when a user creates an item, some fields are automatically filled with some info, such as email address and location?

Authentication uses Active Directory, so every user is identified when using Sharepoint. The only issue is that, being in a big corporate company, I don't have any access to the server, so it must be feasible through configuration of said site/list or using Sharepoint Designer, but I can't and won't be allowed to deploy anything server side.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your limitations, your best bet would be a combination of ajax (I suggest jquery) and sharepoint webservices (if necessary), you need to do a XmlHttpRequest in the userdisp.aspx page, if this page has all the info you need, then get it, otherwise, get the currently logged account and use it to query the webservices (this part I'm not sure if theres a method that will return this info).

This all works using only the browser (Content Editor WebPart) or the SharePoint Designer client.